# buiding bsp using make file in vxworks

Tags: makefile, vxworks, bsp

I am maintaining existing BSP in vxworks and we have make file as shown below

```
CPU = CPU32
TOOL    = gnu

TGT_DIR = $(WIND_BASE)/target

include $(WIND_BASE)/target/h/make/defs.bsp
include $(WIND_BASE)/target/h/make/make.$(CPU)$(TOOL)
include $(WIND_BASE)/target/h/make/defs.$(WIND_HOST_TYPE)


MY_PATH = C:\source\BSP\

/* Build for CPU32: */

BS_ROM_ENTRY        = _bootstrapInit
BS_LD_LOW_FLAGS     = -Ttext 8
BS_ROM_SIZE     = 4000     # Size of first sector in flash SA0.
ROM_TEXT_ADRS       = 8
HEX_FLAGS           = -v -p 8 -a 8

bsexe: $(MY_PATH)/bootstrap.hex


$(MY_PATH)/bootstrapInit.o: $(MY_PATH)/bootstrapInit.s
    $(RM) $(MY_PATH)/boostrapInit.o
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS_AS) $(MY_PATH)/bootstrapInit.s -o $@

$(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.o: $(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.c
    $(RM) $(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.o
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.c -o $@

$(MY_PATH)/comMem.o: $(MY_PATH)/comMem.c
    $(RM) $(MY_PATH)/comMem.o
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(MY_PATH)/comMem.c -o $@

$(MY_PATH)/bootstrap: $(MY_PATH)/bootstrapInit.o $(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.o $(MY_PATH)/comMem.o
    $(RM) $(MY_PATH)/bootstrap
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -e $(BS_ROM_ENTRY) $(BS_LD_LOW_FLAGS) -Map bootstrap.map \
        -o $@ $(MY_PATH)/bootstrapInit.o $(MY_PATH)/bootStrapStart.o $(MY_PATH)/comMem.o
    $(ROMSIZEPROG) -b $(BS_ROM_SIZE) $@
    $(LDOUT_CONV) $@
    @echo hi   // question here line 1

$(MY_PATH)/bootstrap.hex: $(MY_PATH)/bootstrap
    $(RM) $(MY_PATH)/bootstrap.hex
    $(BINHEX) $(HEX_FLAGS) $(SECT_SPEC)$(MY_PATH)/bootstrap$(TXT_OFFSET) \
        $(IMI_SPEC)$(IMI)$(IMI_OFFSET) > $@$(MAP_EXT)
    -@ $(MV_BIN)
          @echo hi   // question her line 2
```

When I am building using above make file, I am seeing output of "hi" of line 1 and I am not seeing output of line2. What might be problem. I am not an make file expert trying to understand and fix the customer issue .

Another question what "$(LDOUT_CONV)" and -@ $(MV_BIN) stands for and what actions are taken when make file sees these lines.

Thanks.

Comment: To know what `$(LDOUT_CONV)` is doing you would need to find what is setting the value of that variable in your build setup. A leading `-` tells make to ignore errors. A leading `@` tells make not to print the command before running it. The story with `$(MV_BIN)` is the same as with `$(LDOUT_CONV)`.

Comment: You are running `make` or `make bsexe` when you are testing this? How do you know which `hi` output you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have exactly one tab separate ahead of line 2 statement? If it is not, this statement can no be executed.

"$(LDOUT_CONV)" and $(MV_BIN) are defined variables other files, you can find them to check what does they do.